# Existe algum serviço online que faz requisições em uma determinada url?

Tags: url, time, rotas, requisição

Preciso que seja feita uma requisição `GET` em uma url a cada 5 minutos. Existe algum serviço gratuito que faça isso?

Comment: Acredito que não exista nada assim gratuito, mas você não pode programar um e hospedar em alguém host gratuito?

Comment: @RicardoPontual desde que funcione

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para URL estática eu uso esse site: https://uptimerobot.com/

Dá pra configurar vários intervalos de 5 minutos ou mais, até 50 URLs. Menos que 5 minutos só pagando. Agora se precisa passar parâmetros dinâmicos para URL terá que procurar alguma API ou usar algum cronjob.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, funcionou... Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, obrigado

Comment: Haha, eu tentei fazer CronJob, mas o local que hospedei não me da suporte, infelizmente tive que usar essa "alternativa provisoriamente permanente".